# Equidistant CSS Menu Flush on Left and Right sides

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how I can accomplish the following responsive menu:

```
Link1  Link2  Link3  Link4
__________________________
```

The first link needs to be left aligned and the last link needs to be flush with the right edge of the container. The nav container has a border-bottom so Link1 and Link4 should be flush with the border.

Right now I'm using a margin-right percentage and adjusting it with my break points. This somewhat works but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: show your code to us..

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think there is a way to do this with all links inside of a list. I would take the approach where the last and first links are spans outside of the list and then center align the middle grouping. It's not unsemantic to do this, depending on the context of the content in the menu items.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-module" role="navigation"> 

    <span class="menu-module-link menu-module-link--first">Link 1</span>

    <ul class="menu-module-list">
        <li class="menu-module-link">Link 2</li>
        <li class="menu-module-link">Link 3</li>
        <li class="menu-module-link">Link 4</li>
    </ul> 

    <span class="menu-module-link menu-module-link--last">Link 5</span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.menu-module {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-module-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.menu-module-link {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-module-link--first {
    float: left;
}
.menu-module-link--last {
    float: right;
}
```

See this example I put together: https://jsfiddle.net/adw5hwq7/2/